# Why do I get the 'module' not callable error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, error-handling, data-analysis

I am kind of new to python. I am trying to do a statistical analyse on acceleration data.

I am trying to do a PCA plot with my data. But I get the following error:

```
File ~\OneDrive - ##\##\Pyth\untitled0.py:41 in <module>
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I do not know what is wrong with my script. Maybe someone knows.

This is part of my csv (the last column is a class (1,2,3):

```
-0.875,-0.143,0.516,2.0
-0.844,-0.143,0.548,2.0
-0.844,-0.143,0.516,2.0
-0.844,-0.143,0.548,2.0
-0.844,-0.143,0.548,2.0
-0.844,-0.143,0.516,2.0
-0.844,-0.143,0.548,2.0
```

And this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

## find dir
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\##\OneDrive - ##\##\Pyth\HAR2')
os.getcwd()


## read csv
df = pd.read_csv('dataframe_0.csv', delimiter=',', names = ['x','y','z','target'])


features = ['x', 'y', 'z']

# Separating out the features
x = df.loc[:, features].values

# Separating out the target
y = df.loc[:,['target']].values

# Standardizing the features
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)


pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])

finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df[['target']]], axis = 1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,3) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)

targets = [1,2,3]
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDf['target'] == target
    ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 1']
               , finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 2']
               , c = color
               , s = 50)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

Comment: Import typo: `import matplotlib as plt` should be `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. With the former, `plt.figure` references the _module_ `matplotlib.figure`, not the function `matplotlib.pyplot.figure`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *MatPlotLib* ([[MatPlotLib]: API Reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index)) import statement should be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

or

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

The beauty of this situation (which makes the error harder to find) is a coincidence. *figure* name exists under both:

- *matplotlib* - as a **module**
- *matplotlib.pyplot* - as a **function** (this is the needed one)

Example:

> ```py
> >>> import matplotlib as mpl
> >>>
> >>> mpl
> <module 'matplotlib' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\VEnvs\\py_pc064_03.09_test0\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py'>
> >>> mpl.figure
> <module 'matplotlib.figure' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\VEnvs\\py_pc064_03.09_test0\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\figure.py'>
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> >>>
> >>> plt
> <module 'matplotlib.pyplot' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\VEnvs\\py_pc064_03.09_test0\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\pyplot.py'>
> >>> plt.figure
> <function figure at 0x000001C31C139D30>
> ```